# Average value for Money Datatype

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, average, postgresql-8.4

The following is the "pc" table which contains details about pc.

```
user=> SELECT * FROM pc;
 code |  model   | speed | ram  |  hd  | cd  |  price  
------+----------+-------+------+------+-----+---------
  101 | Imac     |  2000 | 4096 |  500 | 16x | ₹550.00
  102 | G450     |  1500 | 2048 |  500 | 8x  | ₹450.00
(2 rows)
user=>
```

Now I want to take the average value of price. So tried the following way. But it produce error.

```
user=> SELECT AVG(price) FROM pc;
ERROR:  function avg(money) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG(price) FROM pc;
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
user=>
```

So, what is the way to get the average value of the price column which is in money datatype.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I find the money data type utterly useless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(price::numeric) FROM pc;
```

or

As per PostgreSQL 8 .4's [Monetary Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-money.html)

```
select avg(regexp_replace(price::text, '[$,]', '', 'g')::numeric) from pc
```

Comment: No it produce same error as Rahul Tripathi answer's.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.4.3 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 32-bit

Comment: @mrg just execute `select price::numeric from pc limit 2` and reply back

Comment: @mrg can you try this one `select avg(regexp_replace(price::text, '[$,]', '', 'g')::numeric) from pc` ??

Comment: Yes. The regular expression gets worked... Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
SELECT AVG(price::money::numeric::float8) FROM pc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove Rupee symbol ( ₹ ) first.

[How do I remove the first characters of a specific column in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982819/how-do-i-remove-the-first-characters-of-a-specific-column-in-a-table)

after that `SELECT AVG(price::numeric) FROM pc;`  this query work fine.

or you can try:

```
SELECT AVG(RIGHT(price,-1)::numeric) FROM pc;
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVG` takes `smallint, int, bigint, real, double precision, numeric, or interval` as an argument and as per your table it seems you have not stored it as one of them.

Either cast the value to any one of them or change the column data type to work with AVG in postgresql.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: Even though it produce error while casting from money to some other data type.

Comment: because you have ₹ in your string value.. string replace can work though

Answer (score 0):

you can try using regular expression. 
instead of `SELECT AVG(price) FROM pc`
replace `price` with `regexp_replace(price::text, '[$,]', '', 'g')::numeric`