# Remove a certain repeated leading character from a string but only to a specific length, and keep longer strings that don't start with that character

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I am looking for a way to transform input numbers into a zero-padded format of a specific length, e.g. `5`, for example:

```
1506       --> 01506
201        --> 00201
0000306    --> 00306
```

If there is an input that is *longer* than that length but doesn't start with zero, it should be left at that length, for example:

```
123456     --> 123456
```

but also:

```
0000123456 --> 123456
```

I've already figured out how to add leading zeros for shorter inputs using `REPLICATE`:

```
REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(@Input)) + @Input
```

It's more complicated to shorten numbers, though.  None of the articles I found (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982819/how-do-i-remove-the-first-characters-of-a-specific-column-in-a-table), [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1145035.aspx?Trim%20leading%20zeros%20from%20a%20varchar%20column%20), [this](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/19/sql-server-removing-leading-zeros-from-column-in-table/), etc.) addressed removing *only* up to a certain number of leading characters; it's always about removing *all* leading characters of a certain value.

Other than looping, is there a fairly-concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I could combine an approach from the referenced articles with my  stated solution for adding leading characters, i.e. remove all leading characters and then build them back up to the desired length, if necessary, so I came up with this:

```
SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, PATINDEX('%[^' + '0' + ']%', @Input+'.'), LEN(@Input))
IF (LEN(@Input) < 5) SET @Input = REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(@Input)) + @Input
```

** NOTE: if anyone has a shorter or clearer way to do this, I'd be very happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it out there here's another possibility, and feel free to do a speed test between this and the previous solution to see which is faster..

```html
SET @YourChar = RIGHT('00000' + CAST(@YourNumber as varchar(5), 5)
```

Comment: I thought that, until the OP said they want `'0000123456'` to return `'123456'`.

Comment: This won't work for strings longer than 5 characters, which the OP wants to return in full

Comment: Good catch.  Change the 5 to a 6 then.  I used this method for a wompload of SSIS feeds that generate flat files for things like banking, air transportation, and insurance where for some reason the client wanted zero padded numbers.

Comment: But then `RIGHT('00000' + CAST('00123' as varchar(5)), 6)` would return `'000123'`; which is also wrong.

Comment: Uhh ... Change both 5's to 6.  And add another zero.  SET @YourChar = RIGHT('000000' + CAST(@YourNumber as varchar(6), 6)

Comment: Read the question carefully, the OP wants results of different length depending on the input. A solution with `right` will always return the same length. It's too simple for this problem.

Comment: Hmm.  You are correct, so my solution won't work.  As I don't have anything to add to this expression that would work then I'll withdraw from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `cast` to bigint to get rid of the leading zeroes, and a `case` statement to prefix zeroes if the input is too short:

```
declare @input varchar(max) = '000000001';
declare @length int = 5;

select  case
        when len(cast(@input as bigint)) < @length 
        then replicate('0', @length - len(cast(@input as bigint))) + @input
        else cast(@input as bigint)
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to int to drop the leading 0 then cast back to varchar

```
declare @T table (iv varchar(10));
insert into @T values ('1506'), ('201'), ('0000306'), ('123456'), ('0000123456'), ('0'), (''), ('2'), ('12');
SELECT  t.iv, cast(t.iv as int) ivInt, cast(cast(t.iv as int) as varchar) ivIntVarchar
      , case when cast(t.iv as int) >= 100000 then cast(cast(t.iv as int) as varchar)
                                              else RIGHT('00000'+ cast(cast(t.iv as int) as varchar), 5) 
        end as pad
from @T t;
```