# SQL Server remove double quote text qualifiers from column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have loaded a table where the column names and the data in every column is qualified with `"` (double quotes) e.g. `"abcd"`. I need to now produce a 'clean' table with these double quotes *wrappers* removed from the column headers and the data. Note that the underlying data itself can have double quotes in it e.g. `"abc " d"`. I've included sample data below which can be copy-pasted in a Notepad file (ANSI encoded). Note that the column delimiter is `¬`.

Removing the quotes from the column headers should be fine as I can just do a find and replace in the script when creating the new table. But, for the data, the only way I can think of is to use something like `select replace('"abc " d"', '"', '')`. However, this would also remove the 'actual' quotes in the data and moreover is pretty crude.

Can anyone provide a better solution please?

**Sample Data**

```
"ID"¬"X_REF"¬"STRAW_ID_LOCAL"¬"COMMENT"
"B9890"¬"99999      "¬"ALTER   "¬"Dullovi Center FARG cascade                                                                                                          "
"J555"¬"2134 "¬"ERHARAM  "¬""PREM Center                                                                                                              "
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982819/how-do-i-remove-the-first-characters-of-a-specific-column-in-a-table  This would be for the leading double quote.  A similar technique can be used with `LEFT` to get the tailing double quote.

Comment: Did you load a CSV/flat file with quoted text fields without specifying the quote character? The quickest solution would be to reload the file with the correct settings

Comment: @squillman So you mean something like this - `SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('"abc " d"', LEN('"abc " d"') - 1), LEN(RIGHT('"abc " d"', LEN('"abc " d"') - 1)) -1) AS MyTrimmedColumn`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it was a flat file with quoted fields and I first used the SQL Wizard to import it. However, the SQL Wizard throws an error as soon as it encounters `"` in the data because it thinks it's a text qualifier. Therefore, I had to load the file using a Python script which doesn't remove the quotes rather loads the file as it is.

Comment: Unless you tell it that the fields are quoted. In this case it doesn't throw.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Even when I tell it that the fields are quoted with double quotes, when it encounters double quotes within the underlying data I think the SQL Wizard thinks it's a text qualifier. So then it throws an error. Unless you know a way to handle that like use an escape character or something?

Comment: Which wizard did you use? The `Import Data` wizard or `Import Flat File` wizard? As for `when it encounters double quotes within the underlying data ` what does that mean? CSV files are *NOT* supposed to contain the quote character inside an unquoted text field. You should post an example of actual contents. Not single values, two or three *unmodified* lines

Comment: It's a `.txt` file. And I used the `Import Data` Wizard not the `Import Flat File` Wizard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've edited the original post to include a couple of lines of sample data. The data contains the header as well and it's the second row which fails to upload. The error is `The column delimiter for column "COMMENT" was not found.`

Comment: This is simply a bad text file. You need to fix the code that produces this file. CSV files *can span multiple lines if they are quoted*. You can't just forget the last double quote. What you posted will cause problems in *all* applications that work with CSVs and flat files

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, that's what I thought. Unfortunately, this was sent by a client and it took them ages to extract and send it. So a re-extract isn't an option. I've managed to load the file into SQL server by writing a bespoke Python script. Now just need to figure out how to remove the leading and trailing quotes from all data.

Comment: In that case clean the file *before* trying to import it. SQL, the language, is very poor at text manipulation. It's a *query* language, not a text manipulation language. BTW 90% of all ETL/Integration projects is cleaning up the source data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's a fair point. I'll try to do that then. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you're lucky and *all* lines behave the same, you may be able to use a script that reads each line, appends a `"` if it's missing, then writes the result to a new file. If there are no multiline fields, you may be able to replace every `\n` with `"\n`. Powershell's `-replace` operator can [replace strings in files](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/08/replace-text-with-powershell.aspx) using regular expressions. You could use eg `-replace '\n', '"\n'` or even `-replace '[^"]\n','"\n'`

Comment: Worst case, you can open the text file in a text editor that supports regular expressions like Sublime Text, NotePad++ or even Visual Studio Code and use text replacement. Modern editors have plugins like [Rainbow CSV](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mechatroner.rainbow-csv) that can help with fixing, preparing and querying CSV files

Comment: Many editors can use Python scripts to manipulate data, or even host [Jupyter Notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support). If you're comfortable with Python, you could create a Notebook to clean up the data and insert it into SQL Server. Finally, SQL Server 2017 added Python script support, which allows you to call a script from SQL, crunch data using eg Pandas and return the data to SQL Server as queryable data, or inserting it into a target table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos great, those are great suggestions, especially the one about being able to use Python with SQL Server 2017 - never knew that. I'll try this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when col like '"%"'
             then substring(col, 2, len(col) - 1)
             else col
        end)
```

Comment: Do you mean `select (case when col like '"%"'
             then substring(col, 2, len(col) - 2)
             else col
        end)`